# Angular App images not displaying on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, angularjs

I have a very strange image loading issue ...

[image]

I am struggling to debug this as it appears only on iPhone (tested using both Safari & Chrome) but works absolutely fine using an emulator (Chrome).

My images are loaded directly from the image folder (example) no angular rendering or dynamic src creation:

```
<div class="text-center">
    <a href="https://www.chess.com/" target="_blank">
        <img src="images/assets/chess.com.jpg" alt="" width="200px" height="80px">
    </a>
</div>
```

The site can be found here: http://fantasychess.online/#/

This is not an attempt to spam my web link, I am simply struggling to identify the problem. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, I have searched low and high for similar questions but nothing relevant was found.

Comment: I've just tried this on my iphone and images appear to be fine, are you sure its not a cache issue?

Comment: I cleared all my phone browser cache yes. I am surprised these have loaded for you. I asked a couple of friends to check using their phones too, they had the same problem as me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of src  use [Angular#ngSource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource)

```
<img ng-src="images/assets/chess.com.jpg" alt="" width="200px" height="80px">
```

Comment: Just going to attempt this solution.

Comment: HTML attributes `width`and `height` does not have a unit. `width="200" height="80"`is correct and not  `width="200px" height="80px"`

Comment: @MattWebb if its work then close the question by accepting it.